# NSInternalInconsistencyException Completion handler passed to webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:decisionHandle was not called

Tags: swift, wkwebview

I'm running into an issue with one of our iOS app tests. Any help to solve is much appreciated!

Test code:

```
    func testOpenExternalBrowser_for_valid_urls() {
    // Given
    let vc = MockDashboardViewController()
    vc.openInternalBrowserCalled = false
    vc.openExternalBrowserCalled = false
    vc.webview = WKWebView()
    vc.webview.navigationDelegate = vc

    // When
    let url = URL.init(string: "https://example.com/restOfUrl")
    XCTAssertTrue(url!.absoluteString.contains("https://example.com"), "initial url string is wrong")
    vc.webview.load(URLRequest(url: url!));
    waitSeconds(duration: 2)

    // Then
    XCTAssertFalse(vc.openExternalBrowserCalled, "openExternalBrowserCalled value is wrong")
    XCTAssertTrue(vc.openInternalBrowserCalled, "openInternalBrowserCalled value is wrong")
}
```

This gives me the error:

> error: -[Tests.ViewControllerTests testOpenExternalBrowser_for_valid_urls] : failed: caught
>   "NSInternalInconsistencyException", "Completion handler passed to
>   -[ViewController webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:decisionHandler:] was not
>   called"

This is the relevant WKWebKit ViewController code:

```
    // MARK: WKNavigationDelegate methods
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    guard let url = navigationAction.request.url, let urlScheme = url.scheme, let urlHost = url.host else {
        //if we can't convert the URL, deny the action
        decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicy.cancel);
        return;
    }

    var isPortValid = false;
    if let urlPort = url.port {
        isPortValid = urlPort == HostDefinitions.PORT;
    } else {
        isPortValid = urlScheme == DashboardConstants.HTTPS;
    }

    if(isPortValid && urlScheme == HostDefinitions.SCHEME && urlHost.compare(HostDefinitions.HOST) == ComparisonResult.orderedSame) {
        openInternalBrowser(url: url, decisionHandler: decisionHandler)
        return;
    }

    decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicy.cancel);
    openExternalBrowser(url: url)
}

func openInternalBrowser(url: URL, decisionHandler:@escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    if(url.path == PathDefinitions.Login) {
        //the user has logged out or visited the login page. We will now de-auth them and direct them back to the login page
        OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
            AuthManager.logout()
            _ = self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true);
        }
        decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicy.cancel);
    } else {
        decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicy.allow);
    }
}

func openExternalBrowser(url: URL) {
    AppManager.openExternalBrowser(url: url)
}
```

Any ideas? I've tried adding a return statement and adding the decision handler to the function openExternalBrowser but neither work. The app functions properly (opening external URLs in Safari) but the test fails.

Thank you!

**Edit:**
Here's the MockDashboardViewController code:

```
class MockDashboardViewController: DashboardViewController {

    var openInternalBrowserCalled = false
    var openExternalBrowserCalled = false

    var presentNotificationCalled = false

    var webviewURLString = ""

    override func openInternalBrowser(url: URL, decisionHandler:@escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        openInternalBrowserCalled = true
    }

    override func openExternalBrowser(url: URL) {
        openExternalBrowserCalled = true
    }

    override func presentNotification(notification: DashboardNotification, showAlertView: Bool) {
        presentNotificationCalled = true
    }
}
```

Comment: "This is the relevant WKWebKit ViewController code" But is it the relevant MockDashboardViewController code? — Also, `waitSeconds` is wrong. There is a way to test asynchronous stuff and that isn't it. Indeed, one could argue that you might be testing the wrong thing; you should be mocking your `decidePolicyFor`, not testing it under real circumstances with a real web view; we already know that a web view works, so testing it is pointless.

Comment: Hi @Matt; thanks for responding! I've added the MockDashboardViewController code. Would I just need to call decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicy.allow); in the mocked controller instead?

Comment: Yes, or call `super`. See the full explanation in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is correct. You are saying:

```
let vc = MockDashboardViewController()
vc.webview.navigationDelegate = vc
```

So the web view's navigation is not your "relevant WKWebKit ViewController", which I presume is a DashboardViewController, but a subclass of DashboardViewController, namely MockDashboardViewController. And it says:

```
override func openInternalBrowser(url: URL, decisionHandler:@escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    openInternalBrowserCalled = true
}
```

Okay, so what happens when `decidePolicyFor` is called? It isn't implemented in MockDashboardViewController, so DashboardViewController's implementation is called:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    if(isPortValid && urlScheme == HostDefinitions.SCHEME && urlHost.compare(HostDefinitions.HOST) == ComparisonResult.orderedSame) {
        openInternalBrowser(url: url, decisionHandler: decisionHandler)
        return;
    }
}
```

And that's all that happens along that path of execution. Now, where in all of that is the `decisionHandler` called? Nowhere. The runtime is perfectly correct.

It's true that `decisionHandler` would have been called in DashboardViewController's implementation of `openInternalBrowser(url:decisionHandler:)`. That is why the app runs fine when you run the app (not testing). But in your testing subclass, you overrode that — and you didn't call `super`, so you threw away those calls to the `decisionHandler`.

Comment: This is a dumb question (I don't write much swift), but how do I call super from the openInternalBrowser function in MockDashboardViewController? I want to just take the passed in values from the the mocked function back to the superclass DashboardViewController function of the same name. However, I end up with "Swift Error: Editor placeholder in source file" or "Cannot convert value of type 'URL.Type' to expected argument type 'URL'.

Comment: `super.openInternalBrowser(url:url, decisionHandler:decisionHandler)`.

Comment: D'oh - Had the object type and name swapped around. Thanks again for all of your help; it's nigh time to go read your book.

Comment: Glad to help. By the way, once you provided the needed code (i.e. MockDashboardViewController), this turned into a well-asked question. Bravo.